Shared library need to add in android.bp
I have created a shared lib named liberCore.so and this lib I have put into where is my all src files and this file having some headers which I kept into include folder this lib I am unable to add into android.bp file for making build
how can I add my lib into android.bp?

This question is similar to: How to include prebuilt library in Android.bp file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
